# How to understand output from a Multiclass Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, azure-machine-learning-service, multiclass-classification

Built a flow in Azure ML using a Neural network Multiclass module (for settings see picture). 
 [image]

Some more info about the Multiclass:

[image]

The data flow is simple, split of 80/20.

[image]

Preparation of the data is made before it goes into Azure. Data looks like this: [image]

My problem comes when I want to make sense of the output and if possible transform/calculate the output to probabilities. Output looks like this: [image]

My question: If scored probabilities output for my model is 0.6 and scored labels = 1, how sure is the model of the scored labels 1? And how sure can I be that actual outcome will be a 1?

Can I safely assume that a scored probabilities of 0.80 = 80% chance of outcome? Or what type of outcomes should I watch out for?

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Comment: Yes a little, I upvoted it. But I am hoping for more answers

Comment: I don't think you are going to get - this is pretty much standard staff; but what part remains unclear?

Comment: I read your "My answer in Predict classes or class probabilities?" but still didn't get it. 
Is there a way for me to calculate the actual probabilities in % from the "scored probabilities"?

Comment: ?? - You are already getting them - they *are* your Scored Probabilities, 0.973 is 97.3% etc... Strictly speaking, probabilities are numbers in [0,1] such the ones you get, the % conversion is just for easier communication...

Comment: Ok thx, I mark your answer as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, your are in a *binary* classification setting, not in a multi-class one (we normally use this term when number of classes > 2).

> If scored probabilities output for my model is 0.6 and scored labels = 1, how sure is the model of the scored labels 1?

In *practice*, the scored probabilities are routinely interpreted as the *confidence* of the model; so, in this example, we would say that your model has 60% confidence that the particular sample belongs to class 1 (and, complementary, 40% confidence that it belongs to class 0).

> And how sure can I be that actual outcome will be a 1?

If you don't have any alternate means of computing such outcomes yourself (e.g. a different model), I cannot see how this question is different from your previous one.

> Can I safely assume that a scored probabilities of 0.80 = 80% chance of outcome?

This is the kind of statement that would drive a professional statistician mad; nevertheless, the clarifications above regarding the confidence should be enough for your purposes (they are enough indeed for ML practitioners).

My answer in [Predict classes or class probabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367755/predict-classes-or-class-probabilities/51423325#51423325) should also be helpful.