# Probabilistic SVM, regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I've currently implemented a probabilistic (at least I think so) for binary classes. Now I want to extend this approach for regression, and I'm trying to use it for the Boston dataset. Unfortunately, it seems like my algorithm is stuck, the code I'm currently running is looking like this:

```
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

boston = load_boston()

X = boston.data
y = boston.target
inputs_train, inputs_test, targets_train, targets_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

def plotting():
    param_C = [0.01, 0.1]
    param_grid = {'C': param_C, 'kernel': ['poly', 'rbf'], 'gamma': [0.1, 0.01]}
    clf = GridSearchCV(svm.SVR(), cv = 5, param_grid= param_grid)
    clf.fit(inputs_train, targets_train)
    clf = SVR(C=clf.best_params_['C'], cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
              decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=5, gamma=clf.best_params_['gamma'],
              kernel=clf.best_params_['kernel'],
              max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
              tol=0.001, verbose=False)
    clf.fit(inputs_train, targets_train)
    a = clf.predict(inputs_test[0])
    print(a)


plotting()
```

Can someone tell me, what is wrong in this approach, It's not the fact that I get some error message (I know, I've suppresed them above), but the code never stops running. Any suggestions is hugely appreciated.

Comment: You've set your `max_iter` argument to `-1`, so training will only stop once the tolerance `tol=0.001` has been reached. Presumably this tolerance isn't being reached. Try setting `max_iter` to a non-negative integer.

Comment: I just tried changing tol = 1 and max_iter = 15, but no change unfortunately, anything else you see that looks weird?

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code.

- To start with, what is taking forever is the *first* `clf.fit` (i.e. the grid search one), and that's why you didn't see any change when you set `max_iter` and `tol` in your *second* `clf.fit`.
- Second, the `clf=SVR()` part will not work, because:

  - You have to import it, `SVR` is not recognizable
  - You have a bunch of illegal arguments in there (`decision_function_shape`, `probability`, `random_state` etc) - [check the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) for the admissible `SVR` arguments.
- Third, you don't need to explicitly fit again with the best parameters; you should simply ask for `refit=True` in your `GridSearchCV` definition and subsequently use `clf.best_estimator_` for your predictions (EDIT after comment: simply `clf.predict` will also work).

So, moving the stuff outside of any function definition, here is a working version of your code:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
# other imports as-is

# data loading & splitting as-is

param_C = [0.01, 0.1]
param_grid = {'C': param_C, 'kernel': ['poly', 'rbf'], 'gamma': [0.1, 0.01]}
clf = GridSearchCV(SVR(degree=5, max_iter=10000), cv = 5, param_grid= param_grid, refit=True,)
clf.fit(inputs_train, targets_train)
a = clf.best_estimator_.predict(inputs_test[0])
# a = clf.predict(inputs_test[0]) will also work 
print(a)
# [ 21.89849792]
```

Apart from `degree`, all the other admissible argument values you are are using are actually the respective default values, so the only arguments you really need in your `SVR` definition are `degree` and `max_iter`.

You'll get a couple of warnings (*not* errors), i.e. after fitting:

> /databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py:220:
>   ConvergenceWarning: Solver terminated early (max_iter=10000). Consider
>   pre-processing your data with StandardScaler or MinMaxScaler.

and after predicting:

> /databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:395:
>   DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17
>   and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using
>   X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1)
>   if it contains a single sample. DeprecationWarning)

which already contain some advice for what to do next...

Last but not least: a probabilistic classifier (i.e. one that produces [probabilities instead of hard labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367755/predict-classes-or-class-probabilities/51423325#51423325)) is a valid thing, but a "probabilistic" regression model is not...

Tested with Python **3.5** and scikit-learn **0.18.1**