# How to train sklearn svm model(sklearn.svm.SVC) with epochs?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I want to see if the model is converging on my cross validation. How do i increase or decrease epochs in sklearn.svm.SVC?
currently:

```
SVM_Model = SVC(gamma='auto')
SVM_Model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Also how can I see a progress bar during the training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the combination of `max_iter` and `tol` to achieve the convergence.

> **max_iter** int, optional (default=-1)
> Hard limit on iterations within solver, or -1 for no limit.
>
> **tol** float, optional (default=1e-3)
> Tolerance for stopping criterion.

Progress bar support is currently not available in Sklearn now but you can use the `verbose` param to know the progress.

> **verbose**     bool, default: False
> Enable verbose output. Note that this setting takes advantage of a per-process runtime setting in libsvm that, if enabled, may not work properly in a multithreaded context.

Comment: I follow this code: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/image-classification-using-machine-learning-support-vector-machine-svm-dc7a0ec92e01 I identify as "key" command from that link this one: "model.fit(x_train,y_train)" . Where do I put "max_iter" and "tol " in order to do the training with epochs?

Comment: class constructor params. during the SVC class initiation. Refer to the examples [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

Comment: Ok, I changed the command to this: svc=svm.SVC(probability=True, max_iter= 1) and I get this error: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py:231: ConvergenceWarning: Solver terminated early (max_iter=1).  Consider pre-processing your data with StandardScaler or MinMaxScaler.
  % self.max_iter, ConvergenceWarning)

Comment: I am trying this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163095/probabilistic-svm-regression but nothing seems to work with my problem... Any idea?

Comment: max_iter =1 is a very low value, try somewhere around 100 or 200.